# Finding the equation for $ E(x) $

Tags: calculus

Here is the question

Let $E$ be the differential function and satisfying $E(u + v) = E(u)E(v)$ for all $u$ and $v$. Find the equation for $E(x)$ *Hint*: First find $E^\prime (v)$.

I was figured it that the function $E(x) = e^x$. If I put $x = u + v$, then it should be satisfying that

$\begin{align} E(u+v) &= e^{(u+v)} \quad \text{using this property: } e^{a+b} = e^a e^b \\ &= e^u e^v \\ &= E(u)E(v) \end{align}$

And I though it was just only $e^x$, but I'm very confused that the hint tell me that I have to find the $E^\prime (v)$ and I don't really get it.

Please, correct me if my work is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deriving the expression with the variable $u$, we get $E'(u+v) = E'(u)E(v)$. And with $u=0$, we get $E'(v)=E'(0)E(v)$. If we note $c=E'(0)$ and integrate the relation, we get $E(v)=c e^{ax}$ for some $c$.

Then verify it works only for $c=1$.